# Ограничить выбор чекбоксов

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте. Имеется множества чекбоксов. 
Необходимо, чтобы можно было выбрать только один, по принципу как радио-кнопка, но при этом , чтобы была возможность снять параметр.

Возможно лучше использовать радио , но как ее снять при клике на нее ?

Как лучше реализовать ? Спасибо за советы !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876953/how-to-make-a-radio-button-unchecked-by-clicking-it

Comment: что есть  " снять параметр"?

Comment: как выбрать только один чекбокс: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709209/html-select-only-one-checkbox-in-a-group

Answer (score 2):

Я не уверен подойдет ли это, но существует тип input сброс. Он полностью сбрасывает все данные во всей форме, в том числе и значения radiobutton.

Пример:

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other<br>
  <input type="reset">
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

С помощью **javascript** это делается вполне легко.  Используй то, что и задумал ранее "**checkbox**" для них дай **id** и при клике добавляй свойство **selected** так же и в обратную сторону.

Comment: Этот совет совершенно бестолковый. При клике на чекбокс он и так получает свойвство checked (selected не существует), при клике еще раз он его и так теряет. Если делать через js то нужно делать цикл и удалять все checked, после чего установить checked на кликнутом элементе.(прошу прощения, цикл не обязателен, отменить checked у всех input сразу можно селекторами)